# Проблема кеширования запросов

Tags: php, mysql

Как в пхп убрать кеш запросов? Делаю запрос:

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from users WHERE email='$email'",$con);
$user_all = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if ($user_all['pass']=md5($pass))  //md5($pass) пасс из куков или post...
{
   ...
}
```

Вообщем проблема такая: при смене пароля в БД в `$user_all['pass']` хранится старое значение и очень долго; точно не знаю, кеш или что мб, помогите. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//if ($user_all['pass']=md5($pass))
// эквивалент
$user_all['pass'] = md5($pass);
if ($user_all['pass'] == true) ...
```

"=" - присваивание, "==" сравнение.
У вас должно быть

```
if ($user_all['pass'] == md5($pass)) ...
```

Comment: о спасибо да дествительно написал попривычке как в паскале)

Comment: Если помогло, примите ответ плиз (галка слева)